# cross-domain policy file error

Tags: silverlight, wcf, tcptrace-pocketsoap

I am using WCF service (Not RIA) and silverlight I am getting the following error :

> An error occurred while trying to make
>   a request to URI
>   'http://localhost:8732/'. This could
>   be due to attempting to access a
>   service in a cross-domain way without
>   a proper cross-domain policy in place,
>   or a policy that is unsuitable for
>   SOAP services. You may need to contact
>   the owner of the service to publish a
>   cross-domain policy file and to ensure
>   it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to
>   be sent. This error may also be caused
>   by using internal types in the web
>   service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute.
>   Please see the inner exception for
>   more details.

I have tried adding the following to my the clientaccesspolicy.xml file and the crossdomain.xml to the root of my web project. they look like this...

```
<access-policy> 
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="http://*"/>
        <domain uri="https://*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths="true" path="/"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Any ideas why I am getting this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you install Fiddler to see what the client is sending, and what the service is responding? This should give us more information regarding the problem.

Comment: I wish I was able to but the company that I work at doesn't allow me to install fiddler.. any other ideas on how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Network monitor? Or use a browser such as Firefox or IE9 which lets you see the network requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install fiddler, can you download and use TcpTrace? http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/

Answer (score 0):

The clientaccesspolicy.xml needs to be placed at the root of the website hosting your WCF service and not at the root of your web project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with a SOAP WCF service as soon as I moved by WCF service into a *separate* web app from my Silverlight web app project. Even with my clientaccesspolicy.xml in the WCF web app's root, I was still getting this error. The fastest solution for me was to change my WCF service from SOAP to [REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and then finally Silverlight recognized the clientaccesspolicy.xml and the requests started working again.